# rsync escaping parentheses and space

Tags: regex, escaping, rsync

I am banging my head against a wall on this one. I am running rsync from a raspberry pi to a unix smb share.

I have a large exclude list in a file that is largely working except for 3 directories. I have them in the exclude list as:

```
Cloverfield \(\2008\)\ \1080p \BluRay \5.1Ch \x265 \HEVC \ME
The \Layover \2017 \1080p \Blu-Ray \x264 \DD \5.1-ME
Titanic \(\1997\)\
```

I have successfully handled other directories with spaces in them by escaping as you would expect. I am totally confused about why rsync is not picking up the 2nd item. I successfully esapced () when they are followed by [] but for some reason the first one, it is not picking it up even after I escape the parentheses (though it is not followed by a [] which is working).

As for the 3rd one, I have no idea why that one is not working. I have trying it with just a regular escape such as Titanic (1997) but that doesn't work either.

Is there any documentation on this? I've been pouring over similar posts and have had limited success, but these last 3 are killing me.

Thanks for the help. I'm sure it is some combination that I'm not trying but I honestly tried so many different scenarios but it just isn't working.

Comment: I didn't use rsync before but I've never seen this kind of escaping either. Are you sure you need a slash _after_ space characters and escaped ones?

Comment: I am fairly sure. It has worked on other directories in my exclude file for rsync. What is weird is that while the above 3 cases don't work, this does: Christmas \Movie \(1998) \[1080p] which means it doesn't work when ( ) are immediately followed by [ ]

Comment: [Are you sure the slash doesn't come before the space though](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104634)? Anyway, it looks like this question is more fit to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or maybe [Unix.StackExchage](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I appreciate you posting but yes I have seen that post and it is not working, even with the --protect-args

Answer (score 0):

Don't escape spaces within the exclude file defined by `--exclude-from`.

Escaping is used in the command line `--exclude` option so that the bash won't get confused and treat the part after space as a separate argument.

BTW: you are not escaping any spaces in above mentioned lines, as far as I could tell, they fail because of `\x265` in the first and second lines and the trailing `\` in the third.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you please explain a bit more on your BTW point. How am I not escaping any spaces?

Comment: to escape spaces add backslash in front like this `\ ` not after as you were doing

Comment: I don't believe so. Like I mentioned, the above technique successfully escaped the spaces in hundreds of other directories I am excluding. To prove my point, I even did this: The\ Layover\ 2017\ 1080p\ WEB-DL\ x264\ DD\ 5.1-M2Tv per your suggestion but it is not working.